# R: How to generate a squence which fills up a column of a data frame

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, sequence

So lets say i have a data frame (Address) like this:

```
Street        HouseNumber    A   
Fakestreet1   10            bla
Fakestreet2   20            bla
Fakestreet3   30            bla
Fakestreet4   40            bla
```

and I want to add a new column lets call it ID which simply makes something like

`Address$ID <- 1:4` but without having to specify how many observations (rows) are in the database (1: "**to end of column**") to get a result like:

```
ID         Street       HouseNumber  A   
1         Fakestreet1   10           bla
2         Fakestreet2   20           bla
3         Fakestreet3   30           bla
4         Fakestreet4   40           bla
```

So is there are easy possibility to fill up a data frames column with a sequence without specify the length?

Generally what I need is a (easy) way to express:

```
Addresses$ID <- seq(from=1, to="**end of column**", by=1)
```

I dont mean "simple" indexing something like this should also be possible:

```
ID         Street       HouseNumber  A   
4        Fakestreet1   10           bla
5         Fakestreet2   20           bla
6         Fakestreet3   30           bla
7         Fakestreet4   40           bla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Addresses$ID <- 1:length(Addresses$Street)
```

Or maybe:

```
Addresses$ID <- 1:nrow(Addresses)
```

More general way:

```
Addresses$ID <- seq(from = [start], by = [step], length.out = nrow(Addresses))
```

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thanks! :)
Just out of curiosity is there perhaps an even more general solution without specifying a relation to Addresses§Street?

Comment: You could alternatively use for the first case: `seq_along(Addresses$Street)` and for the second case `seq_len(nrow(Addresses))`.

Comment: The second solution is more general, there's no relation with other columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! All solutions serve the purpose.
But what if i wanted to start the "count" with 2? Or start at 1 but make 0.5 steps so that the ID would be 1; 1.5; 2; 2,5;?
Would something like that be possible?

Comment: @Deset welcome to Stackoverflow.  It looks as if you're happy with Franscesco's answer, please consider accepting this answer.  Feedback like that helps make this community what it is.